# Firefox locks up on Ubuntu 14.04 when using the address bar

Tags: 14.04, firefox

I have a problem with firefox. Every time I type something into the address bar (and it seems only there), firefox freezes and i can not do anything. This happens on a freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Thinkpad Edge E431. I did not make any modifications to firefox and also did not install any addons. Does anyone else ecountered this problem or know, how to solve it? A complete reinstalling of Ubuntu also did not help.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Same for me, even though it seems to happen only when I have the iBus input method enables. Extremely annoying, makes Firefox unusable.